# Insert figure in one column

Tags: floats, multicol

While the paper are written in two columns,I want to insert a figure into a column, which means a figure uses 0.5*paper width. At the same time, I need to use `\bicaption{}{}`,which is in `bicaption` package, to create two captions for one figure.

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{bicaption}
\begin{document}
xxxx......
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{figure A}
\end{figure}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

in this case, the figure can not display in a pdf document.
Note, I want to write a paper in one column at the title, and in two column at the text. The text begins at the title page. For example, [image]
Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly: You have a two column document and want to insert a figure which uses the entire paper width, i.e. spans both columns?

Comment: Hi,hbaderts. I am sorry let you misunderstand inversly. my english is poor. I want to insert a figure which uses the 0.5*paper width.Thank you very much!

Comment: Try \columnwidth, since the column is less than 0.5\paperwidth wide.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) if the comments so far don't solve the problem.

Comment: As I say in response to the other copy of this question: you can't. You can't use a float in a `multicols` environment. See page 5 of the documentation.

Comment: @cfr, You are really a kind person, thank you for your encouragement. Could we make a friend on FB?:)

Comment: @DXL Given that the last time I actually looked at my FB page was more than a year ago, there really is not much point! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. You cannot use a float inside a `multicols` environment. This means no unstarred `figure` or `table` environments. You can use the starred versions, although they will behave differently than outside `multicols`.

If you look at the console output or log, you will see a message explaining this, as described on page 5 of the package documentation. The behaviour of the starred versions is similarly explained in the manual.

## EDIT

If you want the *abstract* to be two columns wide, then you can simply use the `twocolumn` option to the class which has no problem with floats, in conjunction with the `abstract` package. For example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[
  \begin{onecolabstract}
    As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal
    of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I
    know, the things in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon
    for our understanding. The paralogisms of practical
    reason are what first give rise to the architectonic of
    practical reason. As will easily be shown in the next
    section, reason would thereby be made to contradict,
    in view of these considerations, the Ideal of practical
    reason, yet the manifold depends on the phenomena.
    Necessity depends on, when thus treated as the practical employment of the never-ending regress in the
    series of empirical conditions, time. Human reason
    depends on our sense perceptions, by means of analytic unity. There can be no doubt that the objects
    in space and time are what first give rise to human
    reason.
  \end{onecolabstract}
]
  \kant[2]
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Example}\label{fig:a}
  \end{figure}

  \kant[3-20]

\end{document}
```

[image: fancy abstract with float]

The particular style of the abstract, including the indentation can then be configured using the commands provided by `abstract`.

Comment: Is there any environment or way that can get the effect like the figure I uploaded, and at the same time can use a float in the text. And thank you very much!

Comment: @DXL Possibly but it is not something I know how to do. If you update your question with an MWE, you will encourage people to put in the effort required to come up with something. Not guaranteed. But somebody might be interested.

Comment: @DXL But see edit above. Since I don't know what you are really trying to do, this may or may not be helpful.

Comment: Yes, it's I want to do! My English is very poor, could you tell me how should I describe the problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, it's I want to do! My English is very poor, could you tell me how should I describe the problem?

Comment: @DXL Well, it is really just that you asked if there was 'any environment' which could do what you wanted, whereas I've changed a class option which is a bit different. Providing a proper MWE in your question would really help clarify what you are trying to do. That is so no matter how good your English. Actually, your English seems fine to me ;).